# Django get_or_create fails to set field when used with iexact

Tags: python, django, postgresql, django-models

I'd like to use `name__iexact` with `get_or_create` to avoid duplication on user entered fields where possible.

My Provider model has a name field which I use in `get_or_create`.

The lookup works fine but when creating an instance for the first time as in the p1/Timber example below (the name

Fails:

```
>>> p1, c1 = Provider.objects.get_or_create(name__iexact="Timber")
>>> p1, c1
(<Provider: >, True)
>>> p1.name
u''
```

Works as expected here:

```
>>> p2, c2 = Provider.objects.get_or_create(name="Cedar")
>>> p2.name, c2
('Cedar', True)
>>> p3, c3 = Provider.objects.get_or_create(name__iexact="Cedar")
>>> p3, c3
(<Provider: Cedar>, False)
>>> Provider.objects.get_or_create(name__iexact="cedar")
(<Provider: Cedar>, False)
```

Is `__iexact` incompatible with the create portion of `get_or_create`, is this expected behavior (and why), or have I run into a Django bug?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

What you're seeing is the correct behaviour.

`get_or_create` is shorthand for 'get and return the object matching `kwargs`, if it doesn't exist, create it using `defaults`'. Your lookup is looking for an object where `name` is a case-insensitive match to `'cedar'`. That object exists, so it is returned. Nothing more, nothing less.

Now if there was no match, Stéphane is right, and you would need to specify `name` in the `defaults` parameter. All lookups containing the lookup separator `__` are stripped from the parameters passed to `create()`.

Comment: Aha. That last sentence is the key. Here it is in the docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/models/querysets/#get-or-create `for k, v in kwargs.items() if '__' not in k`

Answer (score 31):

According to the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/querysets/#get-or-create), you can try to use default args (haven't try this code):

```
p1, c1 = Provider.objects.get_or_create(
   defaults={'name':"Timber"}, 
   name__iexact="Timber"
)
```

It makes sense since you can then have the search and the object creation that differs.