# Django get_or_create with icontains

Tags: django

I'm getting an unexpected result using `icontains` in my `get_or_create` call.

Take the following example:

```
>>>team_name = "Bears"
>>>Team.objects.get(name__icontains=team_name) # returns DoesNotExist as expected
>>>team, created = Team.objects.get_or_create(name__icontains=team_name)
>>>print(created) # Prints True as expected
>>>print(team.name) # Prints an empty string!
```

Why does this create a team with a blank name rather than "Bears"? The reason I'm using `get_or_create` here is that if a subsequent user posts something like `"BearS"` I want to get the correct team, not create a duplicate team with incorrect capitalization.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think here you should split the `get()` and `create()` functionalities instead of using `get_or_create()`, because the `__icontains` lookup works for `get()` only.

Try doing something like this:

```
>>> team_name = 'Bears'

>>> teams = Team.objects.filter(name__icontains=team_name)
# This will filter the teams with this name

>>> team = teams.first() if teams.exists() else Team.objects.create(name=team_name)
# Now your team is the first element of your previous query (it returns a QuerySet with single element) if it exists
# Otherwise, you create a new Team.
```

Comment: good point...didn't realize that `get_or_create` didn't allow `icontains`. I also ended up using `iexact` instead of `icontains` to avoid mistakes in the case that there's a different team called the "Golden Bears", for instance.

Answer (score 6):

Another option besides wencakisa's answer is to include the `defaults` parameter in `get_or_create`, because Django strips lookups containing the `__` separator. See answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29290479/2532070).

The code would be:

```
Team.objects.get_or_create(
    name__icontains=team_name,
    defaults = {
        "name": team_name
    }
)
```

Answer (score 0):

The right way to do it is using Django's function get_or_create(). But instead of "icontains", you should use "iexact" (), unless you want an exact match, in wich case you should use just "exact":

```
Team.objects.get_or_create(
    name__iexact=team_name,
    defaults = {
        "name": team_name
    }
)
```

Outside "defaults" you should put your search terms. If the objects doesn't exist, you should write your creation terms inside 'defaults'